Did "mangled worlds" go anywhere?
"Mangled worlds" is an idea from Robin Hanson that attempts to explain the origin of the Born rule. AIUI, it asserts that interpreted as in MWI, decoherence of a superposition as a result of measurement (i.e. entanglement with the apparatus) isn't exact, instead producing vanishingly small, but non-zero interaction terms. He then supposes that a branch's total amplitude from conventional/Copenhagen-like histories could potentially be lower than the contributions from these interaction terms because, e.g. it is the end result of many measurement outcomes that each have low amplitude. In this case, the interaction term contributes more amplitude to the branch than the conventional history, "mangling" it and removing it as a possible world in the conventional sense. (He seems to be unclear about whether what that state "looks like" phenomenologically, whether it fails to exist entirely or it somehow appears to be a consequence of the measurement that originally creates the interaction terms.) The Born rule then supposedly falls out of counting the remaining "unmangled" worlds.
The article linked above elaborates that whether or not this actually explains the Born rule depends on various characteristics of how amplitude is distributed between worlds, but that seems a very tractable question for physics research. AFAIK, a positive answer would effectively solve the measurement problem by demonstrating the Born rule to be a consequence, rather than axiom, of the Everett model, so it also appears to be potentially a very important question to be researching.
However, I first came across this idea years ago and since then have not heard anything about anyone independently investigating (or refuting) it. Hansen is also not a physicist, so there might well be some flaw in the idea that's so obvious to actual researchers that it's not worth mentioning but I have also not seen anything to that effect either.
Is there a reason that nobody actually in the field has looked into this?

Mark Rubin's paper Probability, Preclusion and Biological Evolution in Heisenberg-Picture Everett Quantum Mechanics considers Hanson's approach to quantum probability as part of a set of approaches he calls preclusion approaches to eliminating events with low probabilities. Rubin tries to develop a preclusion approach in the Heisenberg picture.

What is the use of preclusion of low probabilities?! The Born rule as it is includes all probabilities, low and high! If you want to derive that rule is seems pointless to try to eliminate some amplitudes first. For the Born rule that wouldn't produce the required result...

The rationale in the paper I linked is that the low probability events include violations of the 2nd law of thermodynamics. I doubt this argument is correct but deviating from the Born rule for small probabilities isn't necessarily a show stopping objection. It might be an experimentally testable implication of this theory. There might be good experimental or theoretical objections to it.

It's about the logic: apparently they want to prove the Born rule from the mechanism of QM, but the essence of the proof is that we have to deviate from the mechanism of QM. That doesn't deliver the proof! (Even though it might be necessary in the process, it might be acceptable, no show stopper, and all that... It simply doesn't serve as a description of the proof that we expect to see! And I don't see any other outline offered. It sounds more like a "qui s'excuse s'accuse" situation.)
